# Error on my Logs System Undefined index : HTTPS

Tags: magento-1.9, https

I've a problem with a webservice on my magento.
After an update HTTP to HTTPS of my website (with Let's Encrypt), i've lot of problems.

It writes :

```
ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: HTTPS  in /var/www/usapboutique.fr/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php on line 1025
```

On my Url.php that corresponds to

```
if($_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on'){
    $url = str_replace('http://', '//', $url);
}
```

Someone has an idea of this type of error ?
Thx

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4911544/1286814.